# Laravel Eloquent: select records where one field equals another

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I apologize if this is duplicated. Is it possible in Eloquent ORM to select records where one field equals another? In MySQL this means:

```
SELECT Id, Url, ModelId 
WHERE Url LIKE CONCAT('%', ModelId, '%')
```

Is it possible to do so in Eloquent or I'm bound to using raw queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On field equalling another in the query builder (and eloquent) is `whereColumn('Url', 'LIKE', 'ModelId')` but since you have additional things in the second part you will need to use raw queries like e.g.

```php
DB::table('table')
   ->select('Id', 'Url', 'ModelId')
   ->where('Url', 'LIKE', DB::raw("CONCAT('%', ModelId, '%')"));
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to use `whereColumn` with closures for further processing? eg: if I want to `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = column2+column3` If yes how can I use them?

Comment: You'd still need a `DB::raw` for that since it's a more complex operation, e.g. `where('column1', DB::raw('column2+column3'))`